# How to do the cannon-es body of a three.js torus?

Tags: three.js, webgl, cannon.js

I want to do the cannon-es body of a THREE.js Torus, and I am not finding the right shape. Sadly there's no built-in CANNON.Torus class.

For reference, [This is how a THREE.js Torus looks like](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=geometry#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry):

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannon-Es torus can be made using the static method `Trimesh.createTorus`. It takes the same parameters as `THREE.TorusGeometry`.

You can check out the documentation on the method [here](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/Trimesh.html#createTorus). There is also [this example](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/examples/trimesh).

The following code should work.

```js
// Creates a torus mesh and physical body with the same parameters.
function createTorus({ radius, tube, radialSegment, tubularSegments, arc }){

    /* ---------------------------------- Mesh ---------------------------------- */
    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( radius, tube, radialSegment, tubularSegments, arc ); 
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
        color: 0xffffff,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.castShadow = true;

    /* ---------------------------------- Body ---------------------------------- */
    const shape = CANNON.Trimesh.createTorus(radius, tube, radialSegment, tubularSegments, arc);
    const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
    body.addShape(shape);

    return { mesh, body }; 
}

// Create and add to scene and world
const { mesh, body } = createTorus({ radius: 5, tube: 1, radialSegment: 16, tubularSegments: 16 });
scene.add(mesh);
world.addBody(body);
```